# what is difference of gitlab project activitiy time stamp and commit time stamp?

Tags: push, commit, gitlab

When I commit the source , commit time is changed(first picture)
but project activity history changed nothing!(second picture)

[image: "commit"]

[image: "activity"]

Why is commit time not reflected on project activity?

Comment: Some questions: What version are you running? What role are you logged in with? I see all of this activity in my Project feed, so maybe it's a bug in the version you have or a permissions issue.

Comment: Here is the same issue : https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2764

Comment: You should first try and upgrade your GitLab installation. From what I see you are using a very old deprecated version (2 years old?).

Comment: it is ver 6.0.2 10b0b8f . is it too old??